# How to extract 'alt' value of HTML documents with python?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, extract

I'm learning basic function of Beautifulsoup. I'm wondering which part of code below could be fix to extract number of alt(means numbering of rank list, like 1, 2, 3) on movie rank page. I wrote sample below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'}
    
data = requests.get('https://movie.naver.com/movie/sdb/rank/rmovie.nhn?sel=pnt&date=20200303')
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
    
movies = soup.select('#old_content > table > tbody > tr')
    print(len(movies))   
    
    for movie in movies:
        d_tag = movie.select_one('td.ac > alt')
        if d_tag is not None:
            print (d_tag)
```

I tried few ways to discover out the answer on line starting with 'd_tag = '

movie.select.one('td.ac > alt') (this work but not only 'number' I need.)

movie.select.one('td.ac > img alt')

movie.select.one('td.ac > img > alt')

movie.select.one('td.ac > img.alt')

this is first time to ask a question on this great community, please excuse if my question is awkward.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: output like 1, 2, 3(number of rank list). Thanks!

Comment: Ok...Check out my solution

Comment: @Sushil comments are updated. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

To get all movie titles + rankings, you can use this example:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://movie.naver.com/movie/sdb/rank/rmovie.nhn?sel=pnt&date=20200303'
soup = BeautifulSoup( requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser' )

for row in soup.select('.list_ranking > tbody > tr:has(a)'):
    movie_title = row.a.text
    ranking = row.select_one('.point').text
    print(movie_title, ranking)
```

Prints:

```
그린 북 9.60
가버나움 9.59
베일리 어게인 9.52
주전장 9.52
포드 V 페라리 9.51
아일라 9.49
원더 9.49
당갈 9.47
쇼생크 탈출 9.44
터미네이터 2:오리지널 9.43
보헤미안 랩소디 9.42
덕구 9.41
나 홀로 집에 9.41
월-E 9.41
살인의 추억 9.40
빽 투 더 퓨쳐 9.40
인생은 아름다워 9.39
매트릭스 9.39
라이언 일병 구하기 9.39
사운드 오브 뮤직 9.39
헬프 9.39
포레스트 검프 9.39
안녕 베일리 9.39
글래디에이터 9.39
위대한 쇼맨 9.38
센과 치히로의 행방불명 9.38
토이 스토리 3 9.38
어벤져스: 엔드게임 9.38
클래식 9.38
알라딘 9.38
헌터 킬러 9.37
죽은 시인의 사회 9.37
아이 캔 스피크 9.37
레옹 9.37
동주 9.37
반지의 제왕: 왕의 귀환 9.37
타이타닉 9.36
캐스트 어웨이 9.36
여인의 향기 9.36
집으로... 9.36
굿바이 마이 프랜드 9.35
서유기 2 - 선리기연 9.35
주토피아 9.35
두 교황 9.35
굿 윌 헌팅 9.35
클레멘타인 9.35
히든 피겨스 9.35
세 얼간이 9.35
쉰들러 리스트 9.34
울지마 톤즈 9.34
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej, If I need number of rank list(like 1, 2, 3), how can I fix the code? Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'}

data = requests.get('https://movie.naver.com/movie/sdb/rank/rmovie.nhn?sel=pnt&date=20200303')

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

movies = soup.select('#old_content > table > tbody > tr')

final = {}

for movie in movies:
    try:
        final.setdefault('Ranking',[]).append(movie.select_one('td.ac > img')['alt'])
    except:
        pass

    try:
        final.setdefault('Title',[]).append(movie.select_one('td.title > div > a').text)
    except:
        pass

    try:
        final.setdefault('Rating',[]).append(movie.select_one('td.point').text)
    except:
        pass

for pair in zip(final['Ranking'],final['Title'],final['Rating']):
    print(" , ".join(pair))
```

Output:

```
01 , 그린 북 , 9.60
02 , 가버나움 , 9.59
03 , 베일리 어게인 , 9.52
04 , 주전장 , 9.52
05 , 포드 V 페라리 , 9.51
06 , 아일라 , 9.49
07 , 원더 , 9.49
08 , 당갈 , 9.47
09 , 쇼생크 탈출 , 9.44
010 , 터미네이터 2:오리지널 , 9.43
11 , 보헤미안 랩소디 , 9.42
12 , 덕구 , 9.41
13 , 나 홀로 집에 , 9.41
14 , 월-E , 9.41
15 , 살인의 추억 , 9.40
16 , 빽 투 더 퓨쳐 , 9.40
17 , 인생은 아름다워 , 9.39
18 , 매트릭스 , 9.39
19 , 라이언 일병 구하기 , 9.39
20 , 사운드 오브 뮤직 , 9.39
21 , 헬프 , 9.39
22 , 포레스트 검프 , 9.39
23 , 안녕 베일리 , 9.39
24 , 글래디에이터 , 9.39
25 , 위대한 쇼맨 , 9.38
26 , 센과 치히로의 행방불명 , 9.38
27 , 토이 스토리 3 , 9.38
28 , 어벤져스: 엔드게임 , 9.38
29 , 클래식 , 9.38
30 , 알라딘 , 9.38
31 , 헌터 킬러 , 9.37
32 , 죽은 시인의 사회 , 9.37
33 , 아이 캔 스피크 , 9.37
34 , 레옹 , 9.37
35 , 동주 , 9.37
36 , 반지의 제왕: 왕의 귀환 , 9.37
37 , 타이타닉 , 9.36
38 , 캐스트 어웨이 , 9.36
39 , 여인의 향기 , 9.36
40 , 집으로... , 9.36
41 , 굿바이 마이 프랜드 , 9.35
42 , 서유기 2 - 선리기연 , 9.35
43 , 주토피아 , 9.35
44 , 두 교황 , 9.35
45 , 굿 윌 헌팅 , 9.35
46 , 클레멘타인 , 9.35
47 , 히든 피겨스 , 9.35
48 , 세 얼간이 , 9.35
49 , 쉰들러 리스트 , 9.34
50 , 울지마 톤즈 , 9.34
```

Comment: Thank you @Sushil for your kind answer.

In those code you wrote, it seems I need to setup 'prettytable'.
Is there any way without using that package?
I'd like to solve this problem under my own environment for studying.

And another one-
'class_ ' of your code upper occurs error on debugging. Please share your thoughts ;)

Comment: U can install `prettytable` just by typing `pip install prettytable` in ur command line. There is actually nothing much to setup. Are you allowed to use `pandas`? And `class_` should work. What error does it throw?

Comment: Yes, I can install those packages but it'd like to figure out the method on my own environment - just for learning beautifulsoap package ;)

About error, more accurately saying, it doesn't occur error but it returns nothing (I guess it because by not setting up those packages you suggested)

Comment: Ok...Are u allowed to use `pandas`?

Comment: Nope, on my environment, 'requests', 'beautifulsoup' and 'pymongo' packages are set-up.

Comment: Ok...Check out my latest edit. I have done it without using any additional packages.

Comment: Appreciate a lot with your works. Your codes work as well but - What I need is finding out the way with using the codes upper I wrote, like

movie.select_one(#script)

Thank you again.

Comment: U wanna use `movie.select_one`? U don't wanna find elements with their `class_name`?

Comment: I have edited my code so that it only uses `.select_one`. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The function 'movie.select_one' needed one more bracket outside.. then it works. Thanks!

Comment: big appreciate with your help, but your code is not correspond perfectly as what I need. (I'm still confused that why I need to cover values with another bracket to make one more value to find 'alt'

Comment: What r u confused abt? Can u elaborate more on it?